# how create xml from java object using jaxb

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

How can i create following type xml in java using jaxb

```
<myInfo>
 <firstName>MyfirstName</firstName>
 <lastName>MyLstNme</lastName>
 <contactList>
  <contact>
   <id>001</id>
   <name>name1</name>
  <contact/>
  <contact>
   <id>002</id>
   <name>name2</name>
  <contact/>
  <contact>
   <id>003</id>
   <name>name3</name>
  <contact/>
 </ContactList>
</myInfo>
```

Bean Classes are..

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "myInfo")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MyInfo {
    @XmlElement(name = "firstName")
    public String firstName;

    @XmlElement(name = "lastName")
    public String lastName;

    @XmlElement(name = "contactList")
    public ContactList contactList;
   ...getter setter
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "contactList")
public class ContactList {
    @XmlElement(name = "contact", type = Contact.class)
    public List<Contact> list = new ArrayList<Contact>();

    public ContactList() {
    }

    public ContactList(List<Contact> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

   ...getter setter
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "Contact")
public class Contact {

    @XmlElement(name = "id")
    public String id;

    @XmlElement(name = "name")
    public String name;

   ...getter setter
```

And Exception

```
objData ToXML 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
==
Class has two properties of the same name "id"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String java8javafx8.Contact.getId()
        at java8javafx8.Contact
        at public java.util.List java8javafx8.ContactList.list
        at java8javafx8.ContactList
        at public java8javafx8.ContactList java8javafx8.MyInfo.contactList
        at java8javafx8.MyInfo
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String java8javafx8.Contact.id
        at java8javafx8.Contact
        at public java.util.List java8javafx8.ContactList.list
        at java8javafx8.ContactList
        at public java8javafx8.ContactList java8javafx8.MyInfo.contactList
        at java8javafx8.MyInfo
Class has two properties of the same name "name"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String java8javafx8.Contact.getName()
        at java8javafx8.Contact
        at public java.util.List java8javafx8.ContactList.list
        at java8javafx8.ContactList
        at public java8javafx8.ContactList java8javafx8.MyInfo.contactList
        at java8javafx8.MyInfo
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String java8javafx8.Contact.name
        at java8javafx8.Contact
        at public java.util.List java8javafx8.ContactList.list
        at java8javafx8.ContactList
        at public java8javafx8.ContactList java8javafx8.MyInfo.contactList
        at java8javafx8.MyInfo
```

How create Bean Class and Bean List Class??

Comment: You will have tried something. Show it to us!

Comment: take this tutorial young soldier: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JAXB/article.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok hear you go:

Make one class call MyInfo as:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="myInfo")
public class MyInfo {

private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>(0);


public MyInfo(){}

public MyInfo(String fName, String lName){
    this.firstName = fName;
    this.lastName = lName;
}

@XmlElement(name = "firstName")
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

@XmlElement(name="lastName")
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
public List<Contact> getContactList() {
    return contactList;
}

@XmlElement(name = "contactList")
public void setContactList(List<Contact> contactList) {
    this.contactList = contactList;
}
 }
```

write another class called  Contact as:

```
 public class Contact {

private int id;
private String name;

public Contact(){}

public Contact(int id, String name){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

@XmlElement(name = "id")
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@XmlElement(name = "name")
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

Marshell it with JAXB (create XML) as:

```
 public class Test  {

public static void main(String[] args){
    Contact c1 = new Contact(1, "first");
    Contact c2 = new Contact(2, "second");

    MyInfo info = new MyInfo("Shekhar", "Khairnar");
    info.getContactList().add(c1);
    info.getContactList().add(c2);

    try {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyInfo.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(info, System.out);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

In above eg. I just print the xml output on console you can write in a file also.
out put will be:

```
<myInfo>
 <firstName>Shekhar</firstName>
<lastName>Khairnar</lastName>
<contactList>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>first</name>
</contactList>
<contactList>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>second</name>
</contactList>
```

Comment: Here is a better way you could map this use case:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/22687583/383861

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MyInfo {

   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;

   @XmlElementWrapper
   @XmlElement(name="contact")
   private List<Contact> contactList;

   // getters & setters

}
```

Things to note:

- JAXB is configuration by exception so you only need to annotate where you want the XML representation to differ from the default.
- By default JAXB treats public fields and properties as mapped.  If you want to treat only fields as mapped you should specify `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)`.
- The mapped fields can be private.
- `@XmlElementWrapper` is used to add a grouping element to a collection.
- When `@XmlElement` is used on a collection it applies to each item in the collection.